# Visual Studio post-Request to own Rest Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, rest, xamarin

here what i got:
- a Mysql database (including the necessery tabels etc)
- NODE.JS with my app.js file, that creates me a RestApi from the data in the DB
- a Xamarin forms app with the nuget Packetes: *microsoft.net.http and *newtonsoft.json (i guess it doens´t matther if it is a Xamarin forms or WPF or whatever for now.)

here whats working: in my xamarin forms app, i can get a list from the data using the rest api. that actually works.

what i want/doesnt work: the post request. so here s my code in c# and .js, maybe you can see the problem:
c#:

```
    private const string Url = "http://localhost:3003/einkauf_add";
    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var nahrungsmittel = new Einkauf { Essen_Name = Name.Text, 
            Stueckzahl = int.Parse(Stueckzahl.Text) };


            //RESTAPI
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nahrungsmittel);
           await _client.PostAsync(Url, new StringContent(content));}
```

(only the nesecerry part, dont wonder about missing stuff like '}' )

and app.js:

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 const morgan = require('morgan')
 const mysql = require('mysql') 

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(morgan('short'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))


function getConnection(){
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: '**',
        password: '**',
        port: **, 
        database: 'test_db'
        })
}


//here should be the foult. i guess its where i get the "Stueckzahl or
 //Essen_name", but dont know how to fix
app.post('/einkauf_add',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("Trying to create new speise: "+req.Stueckzahl)

    const Essen_NameN = req.body.Essen_Name
     const StueckzahlN = req.Stueckzahl
    const queryString = "INSERT INTO Einkauf (Essen_name, Stueckzahl) values (?,?)"
    getConnection().query(queryString,[Essen_NameN, StueckzahlN], (err, results, fields)=>{
    if (err){
        console.log("Failt to insert: "+err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
        return
    }   
    res.end()
    })

})

//this is working:
app.get('/user/:id', (req, res) =>{
console.log("fetching user with id: "+ req.params.id)

    const connection = getConnection()

        const userId =  req.params.id
        const queryString = "SELECT * FROM test_user WHERE id = ?"

        connection.query(queryString,[userId], (err, rows, fields)=>{
                            if(err){
                console.log("Failed >>"+err)
                res.sendStatus(500)
                return
            }
        console.log("think its successfully")
            res.json(rows)
        })

    //res.end()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing the request object in JSON format from the client, you need to parse it back to JSON in the server. For that you need to add the below line in the server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

After which, the request object properties will be available in: `req.body`.

Additionally you will need to change the C# code to use an overloaded constructor for `StringContent`. This change is necessary so that the "Content-Type: application/json" header is sent along with the request, which will let the server know the content type is JSON and hence the server will use the JSON parser for parsing.

```
await _client.PostAsync(Url, new StringContent(content, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Comment: there s still an error... i added the app.use thing and i changed it like this.   console.log("Trying to create new speise: "+req.body.Stueckzahl)
  
  const Essen_NameN = req.body.Essen_Name
      const StueckzahlN = req.body.Stueckzahl, but still a errer "req.body.essen_name is undefinded"

Comment: could you see what is the value in req.body in debug mode or printing to console.log? `console.log(req.body);`

Comment: it sais "undefined" and later:  ' essen_name cannot be null'

Comment: i also tried to add 'toString()' but there still seems to be the issue in getting the posted data. i think the problem is on the bodyparser/my way to use it

Comment: okay. I figured out the issue. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Let me know if it is still not working at your end. I have it working at my end.

Comment: thanks a lot, its working now (y)! i tried with restSharp nuget insted if the httpClient i tried RestClient, that also worked. but for my using, your answer is the better solution, and it works